# ASGI errors when deploying Django project for production

Tags: django, django-channels, django-deployment

I want to deploy my django project and I used ASGI server I applied all steps from the official django website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/asgi/

But it does not work I tried a lot of ways and solutions, but it all fails.

By the way, I want to deploy the project on heroku hosting, it fails on heroku too.

This is the output I get when trying to run the server using:

- Daphne
- Gunicorn
- Uvicorn

  ```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 63, in init_process
    super(UvicornWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/Documents/tests/core/asgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
  ```

### Another error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 170, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 232, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./core/asgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

### Another error output

```
[2021-05-03 01:16:56 +0300] [77956] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-05-03 01:16:56 +0300] [77956] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (77956)
[2021-05-03 01:16:56 +0300] [77956] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2021-05-03 01:16:56 +0300] [77958] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 77958
[2021-05-02 22:16:56 +0000] [77958] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 63, in init_process
    super(UvicornWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/Documents/tests/core/asgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/asgi.py", line 12, in get_asgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 124, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.pyenv/versions/3.8.9/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/apps.py", line 4, in <module>
    import daphne.server
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncioreactor.install(twisted_loop)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/asyncioreactor.py", line 307, in install
    reactor = AsyncioSelectorReactor(eventloop)
  File "/home/ibrahim-pc/.local/share/virtualenvs/tests-IiD-aUH2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/asyncioreactor.py", line 60, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: SelectorEventLoop required, instead got: <uvloop.Loop running=False closed=False debug=False>
[2021-05-02 22:16:56 +0000] [77958] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 77958)
[2021-05-03 01:16:57 +0300] [77956] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-05-03 01:16:57 +0300] [77956] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```